# HikariCP doesn't detect DB DNS change

Tags: postgresql, clojure, amazon-rds, hikaricp

In our application we are using HikariCP with Postgres. The application connects to the DB through a CNAME (the DB is behind the CNAME).

Changing the value of the CNAME to a different DB (in our case replica is promoted to master) doesn't get reflected in our connection pool. The queries still try to fetch data from the old DB. HikariCP makes the changes only when the `maxLifeTime` is over or if we restart the application.

The `maxLifeTime` is set to 30 min and `idleTimeout` is set to 10 min (which are the default values of HikariCP).

**Question:** Is there a way for HikariCP to find out the connection is lost and recreate fresh connections from the passed `serverName` without waiting until `maxLifeTime` expires?

**What I have tried:** I made the `maxLifeTime` to be 2 min. In the worst case my application will be off by 2 min until new connections are established. But making it 2 min we are instructing HikariCP to make new connection every 2 min. Is this a good approach? I see people suggesting to give a value some what between 15-20 min or some value less that the DB connection `maxLifeTime`.

P.S. The application is on clojure-1.7, HikariCP-1.7, postgres-9.6

EDIT: To clarify why I am putting DB behind CNAME is to create a similar setup as AWS RDS with multi AZ environment, where if the master DB goes for for backup another DB starts serving the requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is here ... [Setting the JVM TTL for DNS Name Lookups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/java-dg-jvm-ttl.html).

In short, there is nothing HikariCP can do if the JVM caches DNS lookups for extended period of time.  You need to address this at the JVM-level.  Also, the TTL of the upstream DNS server will also have a major effect -- also caching until the native DNS TTL expires.

EDIT: Sorry, I missed a key part of the question.  As Taylor notes, you can suspend the pool (you need to enable `allowPoolSuspension`), soft evict the connections, and then resume the pool.  Connections that are "in-flight" at the time of eviction will complete normally and then be immediately evicted when they return to the pool.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of "stale" connections being kept alive to the previously named DB: "Is there a way to ... recreate fresh connections ... without waiting until `maxLifeTime` expires?"

Comment: I just noticed, you are using an *extremely* old version of HikariCP.  I recommend upgrading to the latest version of the Clojure wrapper and HikariCP.  Also, enable DEBUG level logging for the package com.zaxxer.hikari ... you can observe logs of connection lifecycles (creation/retirement).

Comment: @brettw We have a plan to upgrade to the latest HikariCP, but that will take some time. I have enabled DEBUG level to see the logs but the HikariCP doesn't recreate connection pool. I think its not the responsibility of the HikariCP to check DNS change, still wondering if there is a cleaner approach.

Comment: @TaylorWood I have a different approach where the application is  connected to the port which HAProxy is running, (in the same instance) and HAProxy server is polling connection from DB. In this case if the DB is changed then i need to restart the HAProxy server (which starts within millis). But this still requires human interference. Any suggestions?

Comment: @VikashGupta If I can make a tangential suggestion… in my experience, it tends to be easier to deal with dependencies by *always* keeping them up to date. If you have a good QA process where (mostly automated) tests cover your whole project, you will automatically test the incorporated changes as you release. if you leave dependencies out of date, you eventually wind up with a difficult, painful upgrade process because you have years' worth of changes to absorb all at once. To use a metaphor, it's easier to do regular maintenance on your car instead of waiting until the engine seizes up.

Comment: @SarahG I share the same enthusiasm... Will try to implement it

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way for the HikariCP to find out if the connection is lost and need to recreate fresh connections from the passed serverName without waiting till expiring of maxLifeTime reaches?

When you change the CNAME, the previously named DB (and connection to it) is still alive, right? I'm assuming the connection is not really *lost* when DNS changes; the CNAME just points to a different DB replica/instance. HikariCP doesn't check that DNS records have changed, it only cares that the connections are valid.

Here's one idea: you could have some other thread in your program poll for the CNAME change and call [`softEvictConnections()`](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/blob/64d91e8ea35799bae2739d8392b5705627d7758a/src/main/java/com/zaxxer/hikari/pool/HikariPool.java#L362) on your pool when a change occurs. This will immediately close any idle/reservable connections and mark any other connections for eviction.

Or if you're manually changing the CNAME, I suppose you could manually poke your app to do this instead of polling from within.

You could also `suspendPool()` and `resumePool()` if you wanted to stall your DB access while this is happening.

Comment: I have created a scheduler that polls every 30 sec to check for DNS change... But what I fear is that if the CPU spiked to 100% JVM kills random threads to make it stable, and the scheduler thread gets killed them i'm back to square one. :-(

Comment: @VikashGupta If you have Multi-AZ RDS master, you can reboot master with failover after updating CNAME to replica. It would change the IP address of Master RDS and will cause failures with existing pool connections. Also, you will have to set  Postgres driver Read and Socket timeout to fail fast. HikariCP will create new connections and will connect to replica. Please check this out if you run into timeout issue - https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/issues/1286